# How to Add Attribute in a XML CDATA? XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Xml:

```
<Frames>

<bannerFrame1>
      <![CDATA[
      <iframe src="https://image.domain.com/promobanner1.html" height="320" width="629"                scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
      ]]>
    </bannerFrame1>

<bannerFrame2>
      <![CDATA[
      <iframe src="https://image.domain.com/promobanner2.html" height="320" width="629"                scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
      ]]>
    </bannerFrame2>

</Frames>
```

XML: bannerFrame1/iframe CDATA  source Value may look like something like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
     <body>
       <div>
        <img src="banners/banner1.gif" border="0" alt="Banner"/>
       </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

XSLT: Im getting the CDATA value of the bannerFrame1

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="Frames/bannerFrame1" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
 </xsl:template>
```

Im trying to add a google analytic event tracking code on the image from CDATA "bannerFrame1".
How can I add an onclick attribute on  `<img src="banners/banner1.gif" border="0" alt="Banner">` while getting the CDATA value of `<bannerFrame1>`? Is it really possible? Thanks in advance.

```
Expected output: 
 <iframe>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
         <body>
           <div>
            <img src="banners/banner1.gif" border="0" alt="Banner" onclick ="GoogleEventTracker();"/>
           </div>
         </body>
      </html>
</iframe>
```

Iframe source:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custombanner/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custombanner/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>-->
    <title>domain - It's time everyone flies</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="script" http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <meta name="script" http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/soapclient.js"></script>-->
    <style type="text/css">
        img, div, a, input
        {
            behavior: url(iepngfix.htc);
        }
        #nav
        {
            float: left;
            left: 8px;
            margin: 15px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 235px;
            padding-left: 242px; /* for 4 frames */ /*padding-left: 278px; /* for 3 frames */ /*padding-left: 312px; /* for 2 frames */ /*padding-left: 242px; /* for 4 frames */
            margin-left: 1px;
            margin-right: 1px;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
            height: 40px; /*background :url("banners/gradient.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;*/
        }
        #nav li
        {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            list-style: none outside none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 2px;
            padding-right: 4px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            width: 25px;
        }
        #nav a
        {
            border: 1px solid #ffffff;
            display: block;
            padding: 0;
            width: 25px;
        }
        #nav img
        {
            border: medium none;
            display: block;
            height: 20px;
            width: 25px;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        }
        #nav li.activeLI
        {
            background: #ff0000;
        }
        #nav li.activeLI img
        {
            opacity: 1;
            filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="slideshow mainpromo" id="slideshow" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
<!--            <a href="http://www.domain.com/Pages/SeatSalePromo.aspx" target="_top">
                <img src="banners/banner1.gif" border="0" alt="Banner" /></a>-->
            <img src="banners/banner1.gif" border="0" alt="Banner">
        </div>
        <ul id="nav">
        </ul>
        <div class="rightpane">
            <!--<a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_top"><img src="banners/promo-fares.jpg" width="206" height="214" border="0" alt="Thumbnail" /></a>-->
            <img src="banners/lite-fares.jpg" width="206" height="214" border="0" alt="Thumbnail">
            <a href="https://book.domain.com/Register.aspx" target="_top"><img src="images/registernow.gif" width="203" height="20" border="0" alt="See all Low Fares"></a>  
            <!--<center><a href="http://www.domain.com/Pages/WebCheck-in.aspx" target="_top"><font size="2" color="#ff6600">Web Check-In</font></a></center>-->
          <!--<a href="http://domain.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/topdestinatios_btn.gif" alt="" width="149" height="26" border="0" /></a>-->
        </div>
        <div id="alerts">
            <p>
                <strong>Seat Sale Alert! </strong>Be the first to know thePromos. <a target="_top" href="http://www.domain.com/pages/emms-signup.aspx">SUBSCRIBE NOW »</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <!--                <strong>Seat Sale Availability</strong> Find the best time to travel. <a target="_top"
                    href="http://www.domain.com/documents/seat_map.pdf">DOWNLOAD PDF &raquo;</a>-->
            </p>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
        <div id="mascot">
            <img src="images/mascot.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: The question is unclear. When you say _"XML: bannerFrame1 CDATA Value may look like something like this"_, do you mean to say that the `iframe` will contain that HTML, retrieved from `https://image.domain.com/promobanner1.html`?  The _"CDATA value of `<bannerFrame1>`"_ you make reference to is the `<iframe...` tag, not the XML you quoted earlier.

Comment: @Jim yes sir exactly, I want to add an onclick attribute on the image inside the iframe  <img src="banners/banner1.gif" border="0" alt="Banner" onclick ="GoogleEventTracker();"/>

Comment: You haven't provided enough context to answer the question. Where is the XSLT running, in the Browser (Javascript) or on the server?  If it's on the server, here's what's happening: 1) The browser requests the initial page; 2) You generate that response with XSLT. At this point `<bannerFrame1>` generates some HTML containing an `<iframe...>`, which gets sent to the browser. 3) The browser then turns around and requests `https://image.domain.com/promobanner1.html`. This is a separate request from the one that ran your initial XSLT.

Comment: @Jim the requested iframe source were included

Comment: Things are still unclear.  The first two code examples in your post are contradictory. Either the `bannerFrame1` XML tag generates an `<iframe...` or it generates the HTML in the second code block, but not both.  If somebody else understands the question, please edit the post to clarify it.

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind' there not the same CDATA comes from another domain source

Answer (score 0):

If you control image.domain.com, then you can add that attribute without trouble, but you don't need this round-the-houses approach to do so.  If you don't control image.domain.com, you're out of luck. (At least, I devoutly hope so.)

If I have understood your question correctly, you're asking how to use XSLT to change data that is being served by a different server as the content of an iframe in the output of your XSLT stylesheet.  It would be hard for XSLT to do so, since in your example the data are fetched from image.domain.com by the browser, acting on the output of the stylesheet, not by the stylesheet.  If a stylesheet running in the browser tried to retrieve the data directly and insert it in the output document in place of the iframe, the browser would block the attempt as a violation of the same-origin policy.

I'm impressed -- I thought I would never say a good word about the same-origin policy or feel that it serves any useful purpose, but you have proven me wrong.

A stylesheet running on the server might well be able to parse enough of the string value of bannerFrame1 to identify the URI being pointed to, fetch the data, and insert it into the output in place of the iframe.  It may be challenging to get it to display properly.

Or you could make the iframe point not to image.domain.com but to a proxy on your own server, which fetches the data from image.domain.com, inserts your tracking attribute, and hands the modified data to the browser.  (Standard method for overcoming the same-origin policy:  bounce the data off your own server on the way in.  The same-origin policy doesn't keep everyone from including data from other sources, just people who can't set up a proxy.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. You're right, that's what i intend to do. I'm getting the image from image.domain.com and I guess its a bad luck for me Because I don't have an access on it :(  Is there any approach?